# Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (input_1) with 150528 bytes from a Java Buffer with 602112 bytes

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to use my model in the `tflitecamerademo` example.

Here is my model
[image]

The demo crashes with the following reason

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (input_1) with 150528 bytes from a Java Buffer with 602112 bytes.`

I initialize the byte buffer following google's example

```
imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * DIM_BATCH_SIZE * DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y * DIM_PIXEL_SIZE);

imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

DIM_BATCH_SIZE = 1
DIM_IMG_SIZE_X = 224
DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y = 224
DIM_PIXEL_SIZE = 3
```

Then I resize the image to the net resolution and convert it to a byte buffer

```
Bitmap reshapeBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 224, 224, false);
convertBitmapToByteBuffer(reshapeBitmap);


private void convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imgData == null) {
            return;
        }
        imgData.rewind();
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        // Convert the image to floating point.
        int pixel = 0;
        long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < DIM_IMG_SIZE_X; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y; ++j) {
                final int val = intValues[pixel++];
                imgData.putFloat((((val >> 16) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
                imgData.putFloat((((val >> 8) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
                imgData.putFloat((((val) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
            }
        }
        long endTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        //Log.d("Timecost to put values into ByteBuffer: " + Long.toString(endTime - startTime));
    }
```

And last, I run the detection

```
tflite.run(imgData, labelProbArray);
```

Here the crash happens due to the input size being different to to buffer size.

Now, if we multiply by hand 1 * 224 * 224 * 3 * 4 we get 602112, the correct size. Why my code is missing the last multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can just using ImageProcessor `CastOp(DataType.UINT8)` to cast the bitmap into uint8.

```
ImageProcessor imageProcessor;
TensorImage xceptionTfliteInput;
if(IS_INT8){
    imageProcessor =
           new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                            .add(new ResizeOp(INPNUT_SIZE.getHeight(), INPNUT_SIZE.getWidth(), ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
                            .add(new NormalizeOp(0, 255))
                            .add(new QuantizeOp(inputQuantParams.getZeroPoint(), inputQuantParams.getScale()))
                            .add(new CastOp(DataType.UINT8))
                            .build();
    xceptionTfliteInput = new TensorImage(DataType.UINT8);
} else {
    imageProcessor =
          new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                            .add(new ResizeOp(INPNUT_SIZE.getHeight(), INPNUT_SIZE.getWidth(), ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
                            .add(new NormalizeOp(0, 255))
                            .build();
     xceptionTfliteInput = new TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32);
}
xceptionTfliteInput.load(bitmap);
xceptionTfliteInput = imageProcessor.process(xceptionTfliteInput);
```

Comment: but is this bad on processing power

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by type mismatch.
According to model description you have integer type input/output, maybe quantized model.
You are trying to prepare floating point data buffer to feed. There are 2 most common solutions:

1)Prepare uint8 data. Write bitmap pixels as 1 byte uint8s into bytebuffer:

```
imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(DIM_BATCH_SIZE * DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y * DIM_PIXEL_SIZE); // now buffer size and input size match

imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

Bitmap reshapeBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 224, 224, false);
convertBitmapToByteBuffer(reshapeBitmap);


private void convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imgData == null) {
            return;
        }
        imgData.rewind();
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        // Convert the image to floating point.
        int pixel = 0;
        long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < DIM_IMG_SIZE_X; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y; ++j) {
                final int val = intValues[pixel++];
                imgData.putChar((byte)((((val >> 16) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD*255));
                imgData.putChar((byte)((((val >> 8) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD*255));
                imgData.putChar((byte)((((val) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD*255));
            }
        }
        long endTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        //Log.d("Timecost to put values into ByteBuffer: " + Long.toString(endTime - startTime));
    }
```

Also take a look at [tflite support lib](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support), it simplifies way how you deal with input/output data and may come handy.

2)Find model with floating point input and use your code

Comment: Thanks, also had to change output values to bytes.